# How can I get a var in my extended class?

Tags: php

I wish to have a variety of classes that extend an emotions class, each class defines the mood so it can be used in the extended class.

My question is, how can I get the mood var in the extended class, here's what I have so far:

Here's my class:

```
class Happy extends Emotions{

    protected $mood = 'happy';

}
```

Here's what it extends:

```
class Emotions {


public function __construct(){

    var_dump($this->mood);
    die();
}
```

A further question is, is this the best way to go about this? I want to have a core set of methods, but change a variety of vars for the class, so my emotions class has all the methods, and then i have a number of clases, 'happy', 'sad', 'angry' which extend it and set particular vars.

Comment: protected and public vars are accessible in child classes. If you have a very long list of vars then just declare them in parent and can access in child class.

Comment: you can't access child property into parent class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the property in the parent class, and then modify it in the children. That way you can access it on the parent class.

```
class Emotions {

    protected $mood = "";

    public function setMood($mood)
    {
        $this->mood = $mood;
    }
}
```

About the question about if this is a good way to go, it depends very much on what you want to achieve. If your child emotions classes are just a set of attributes it is probably not, since you are not going to add different functionalities for different emotions.

In the other hand, if you want to add specific functionalities to each emotion, but at the same time all emotions share some functionalities, then it is ok to create a Parent class to have those common functionalities so you don't repeat code.

For instance:

```
class Emotion {

    protected $mood = "";

    public function express(){
        echo "I am " . $this->mood;

    }

}

class Happy extends Emotion {

    protected $mood = "happy";

    public function dance(){
        echo "Oh! Yeah!";

    }

}

class Sad extends Emotion {

    protected $mood = "sad";

    public function cry(){
        echo "buaaah!";
    }

}
```

As you can see, all emotions will have a method express, but happy can dance and sadness can cry.

Comment: How would I modify it in the parent class? Create a construct and do $this->mood = 'whatever';??

Comment: You could create a setter method, all children will inherit this method. I will update the code above with the setter method

Comment: Do you want to access to the parent class mood from any new or old instance of this class and child class ?

Comment: Thanks, what would be a better way then, in each emotion (sad, happy etc) I am just going to set a few vars which then emotions class uses. What is a better way to do it?

Comment: Also I've just tested your code, it fails to work, $mood is just '' and not what is set in the happy class.

Comment: If you instance Happy you get an empty $mood? Strange, I just tried and it works. If what you want is to set a bunch of variables, I think there is no need to create inheritance, just pass the variables you want to fill in to the constructor of the Emotion and set them on the constructor.